# Customary command line on mac

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

Can I type 'jp' instead of 'jupyter notebook' every time I enter the terminal? I tried alias the ~/.bash_profile but it didn't work

```
alias jp = 'jupyter notebook'
```

and it says

```
-bash: ‘jupyter: command not found
```

Comment: How exactly did you alias? What do you mean by "does not work"? Does your .bash_profile even get run?

Comment: Did you enter it with spaces around `=`, like above? There must not be any.

Comment: @BenjaminW. can you give an example?

Comment: @Robert thank you for your comment. How do I know whether it's runned?

Comment: You wrote: `alias jp = 'jupyter notebook'`, but it should be `alias jp='jupyter notebook'`.

Comment: And it should go in your `.bashrc` not your `.bash_profile` (which is only sourced in *login*, not *interactive* shells) Your `.bashrc` is sourced in both.

Comment: @ZHU: can I help you more?

Comment: was my answer the solution for you problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this:

**1st ~/.bashrc**

Open **~/.bashrc** with an `editor` your choice and add some lines after `Alias`:

```
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
alias jp='jupyter notebook'
```

Save and close it.

**2nd ~/.bash_aliases**

A little bit more explicit is to `touch` a new file **~/.bash_aliases** and open it with your `editor` oft choice. Add a few lines, save and close it.

```
alias jp='jupyter notebook'
alias la='ls -al'
alias ..='cd ..'
```

In order to reload **bash_aliases** you need to add these lines in **.bashrc**

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
        . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Finally you need to reload the source:

1st way:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

2nd way, after creating the new file:

```
$ source ~/.bash_aliases
```